# Calculating the mutual information between two histograms

Tags: matlab, histogram, information-theory, mutual-information

I've been set a sample exercise by my supervisor, and I'm totally lost as to where I should be heading.

What I've been tasked with is to generate two histograms that approximate Gaussian PDFs. Then, I'm meant to shift the means of the histograms so that they overlap to some extent, and then calculate the drop in mutual information.

I've tried a variety of solutions, but none have given me reliable results so far. What I'm now trying to do is calculate the entropy of each of the histograms, and subtract the entropy of the joint histogram. However, even this is becoming difficult.

Right now, I'm working with the following code;

```
clear all

%Set the number of points and the number of bins;
points = 1000;
bins = 5;

%Set the probability of each stimulus occurring;
p_s1 = 0.5;
p_s2 = 0.5;

%Set the means and variance of the histogram approximations;
mu1 = 5;
mu2 = 8.2895;

sigma1 = 1;
sigma2 = 1;

%Set up the histograms;
randpoints1 = sigma1.*randn(1, points) + mu1;
randpoints2 = sigma2.*randn(1, points) + mu2;

[co1, ce1] = hist(randpoints1, bins);
[co2, ce2] = hist(randpoints2, bins);

%Determine the marginal histogram;
[hist2D, binC] = hist3([randpoints1', randpoints2'], [bins, bins]);

prob2D = hist2D/points;

r_s1 = sum(prob2D, 2)'; %leftmost histogram
r_s2 = sum(prob2D, 1); %rightmost histogram

%Determine p(r) for each of the marginal histograms;
r1 = p_s1*r_s1;
r2 = p_s2*r_s2;

%Determine the mutual information for each of the marginal histograms;
for ii = 1:bins;
    minf1(ii) = p_s1*r_s1(ii)*log2((r_s1(ii))/(r1(ii)));
    minf2(ii) = p_s2*r_s2(ii)*log2((r_s2(ii))/(r2(ii)));
end

minf1(isnan(minf1)) = 0;
minf2(isnan(minf2)) = 0;

Imax = sum(minf1) + sum(minf2);
```

From my (albeit limited) understanding of information theory, the above should have calculated the information "contained" within the first and second histograms, and summed them. I would expect a value of 1 for this sum, and I do indeed achieve this value. However, what I'm stuck on now is determining the joint histogram, and following from that, the joint entropy to subtract.

Is the `prob2D` matrix I've created the joint probability?? If so, how can I use this??
Any insight or links to relevant papers would be much appreciated - I've been googling quite a bit, but I haven't been able to turn up anything of value.

Answer (score 13):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information), mutual information of two random variables may be calculated using the following formula: 
$$ 
I(X;Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} \sum_{x \in X} 
                 p(x,y) \log{ \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)\,p(y)}
                              \right) }
$$

If I pick up your code from this:

```
[co1, ce1] = hist(randpoints1, bins); 
[co2, ce2] = hist(randpoints2, bins);
```

We can solve this the following way:

```
% calculate each marginal pmf from the histogram bin counts
p1 = co1/sum(co1);
p2 = co2/sum(co2);

% calculate joint pmf assuming independence of variables
p12_indep = bsxfun(@times, p1.', p2);

% sample the joint pmf directly using hist3
p12_joint = hist3([randpoints1', randpoints2'], [bins, bins])/points;

% using the wikipedia formula for mutual information
dI12 = p12_joint.*log(p12_joint./p12_indep); % mutual info at each bin
I12 = nansum(dI12(:)); % sum of all mutual information
```

`I12` for the random variables that you generate, is quite low (`~0.01`), which is not surprising, since you generate them independently. Plotting the independence assumed distribution and the joint distribution side by side shows how similar they are:

[image: no mutual information between variables]

If, on the other hand, we introduce dependence by generating `randpoints2` to have some component of `randpoints1`, like this for example:

```
randpoints2 = 0.5*(sigma2.*randn(1, points) + mu2 + randpoints1);
```

`I12` becomes much larger (`~0.25`) and represents the larger mutual information that these variables now share. Plotting the above distributions again shows a clear (would be clearer with more points and bins of course) difference between joint pmf that assumes independence and a pmf that's generated by sampling the variables simultaneously.

[image: some dependency between variables]

The code I used to plot `I12`:

```
figure;
subplot(121); pcolor(p12_indep); axis square;
xlabel('Var2'); ylabel('Var1'); title('Independent: P(Var1)*P(Var2)');
subplot(122); pcolor(p12_joint); axis square;
xlabel('Var2'); ylabel('Var1'); title('Joint: P(Var1,Var2)');
```

Comment: Welcome to CV! i've edited out your introduction to conform to the site style. ("No distractions," as the tour says.)

Comment: Thanks @Alexander F. ! Your answer was very helpful, I'll award you with the bounty!

Comment: can this comparative analysis also be done for continuous r.v.? would the binned histogram plots still apply in the continuous case (if i am discretizing the continuous r.v.)? and what would be coded differently, just the pmf function would be replaced with pdf?

Comment: The OP's example was about normal distribution (they used `randn` Matlab fn) put in discreet bins so I just rolled with that example. I believe that you can increase the number of bins (and points) to get a better approximation of the continuous case. The conclusion will be consistent with this example but the values of `I12` will be different. I have not looked into a truly continuous analysis of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A blog post entitled, “Entropy in machine learning” dated May 6, 2019 (https://amethix.com/entropy-in-machine-learning/) gave a very good explanation and summary of the concepts of Mutual Information, KL Divergence and their relationships to Entropy. It had many informative references and it provided useful Python code supporting their explanations. The code that they provided used the numpy.histogram method to create the inputs for the sklearn.metrics. mutual_info_score while never displaying the actual histograms. You can very easily modify it to display the histograms that you need then use the MI as needed. The code and references that they provided as also very enlighting. You might also benefit from their explanation and use of code to calculate KL Divergence.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import iqr
from numpy import histogram2d
from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score

# Read dataset about breast cancer detection
df = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00451/dataR2.csv")

# Separate input and targets
target = df['Classification']
df.drop(['Classification'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Define mutual information function
def minfo(x, y):
    # Compute mutual information between x and y
    bins_x = max(2,int(2*iqr(x)*len(x)**-(1/3))) # use Freedman-Diaconis's Rule of thumb
    bins_y = max(2,int(2*iqr(y)*len(y)**-(1/3)))
    c_xy = histogram2d(x, y, [bins_x,bins_y])[0]
    mi = mutual_info_score(None, None, contingency=c_xy)
    return mi

# Build MI matrix
num_features = df.shape[1]
MI_matrix = np.zeros((num_features,num_features))
for i,col_i in enumerate(df):
    for j,col_j in enumerate(df):
        MI_matrix[i,j] = minfo(df[col_i],df[col_j])
MI_df = pd.DataFrame(MI_matrix,columns = df.columns, index = df.columns)
print(MI_df)
```

[image]

I find this post, along with the explanation and code provided in the first answer above when combined, to offer a very interesting solution.