# Mutual information formula

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, mutual-information

What is the formula for finding mutual information (MI) feature to feature?
Is this formula correct
$$ \mathrm{MI}=p(t_1,t_2)\log_2\left(\frac{p(t_1,t_2)}{p(t_1)p(t_2)}\right) + (1-p(t_1,t_2))  \log_2\left(\frac{1-p(t_1,t_2)}{(1-p(t_1))p(t_2)}\right)?$$
i am doing a project in sentiment analysis.here pt1t2 is the probability of cooccurence of t1t2 together.so is in the part of finding probabilty of not occuring together,is in the denominator (1-pt1)*(1-pt2) or as given in the equation .

Answer (score 1):

This has already been asked and here is a very good answer with a code:

[Link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/181543/106520)